# html contact form doesn't recognise php file

Tags: php, html, css

------THE CODE HAS BEEN MODIFIED SINCE FIRST POST------

For the life of me, I cannot get this to work. The page mentioned below will not recognise the email.php file in the root theme folder. I've tried everything!

**Purpose**: HTML contact form for a user to submit their details, PHP Script collects the users first name, last name and email address and in turn, redirects them to a thank you page.

**Problem**: HTML contact form displays fine, but when I click on "Okay, send me a voucher code!" it comes up with URL: http://charliesonlinestore.com/free-delivery-coupon-page/email.php with 'Nothing found', when it should be re-directing to a thank you page.

Here is the form code from HTML:

```
<div class="form">

<form method="post" name="landing-page" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/email.php">

First Name<br>
<input type="text" name="first_name"><br><br>

Last Name<br>
<input type="text" name="last_name"><br><br>

Email Address<br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Okay, send me a voucher code!">

</form>

</div>
```

Here is my PHP Script code:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'charlie@charliesonlinestore.com';
$body = 'Here your email body text';
$subject = 'NEW Subscriber';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Lead Generator <Charlie@charliesonlinestore.com>' .
"\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

if($_POST['submit']){
    if(mail($to, $subject, $headers)){
         echo "mail send"; // change this later to your header location
    }
    else{
        echo 'error sending mail';
    }
}
else{
    echo 'no post data';
}
?>
```

**Confirmed points:**

- The email.php is in the root of the theme folder, storefront.
- All items in the example are provided in the root folder, storefront.
- When I tested this on local host (separate server), it worked fine and redirects without issues.

If you have any ideas on why this is happening then I would greatly appreciate it. I've almost completed my very own custom built contact form, lead generation and thank you page!

Just to note, I have checked previous posts and tried things such as putting a '/' infront of the PHP file name and also tried putting the file server address infront of the file name but to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: FYI, you are missing braces `{}` after `if (mail ($to, $subject, $headers))` so your exit is fired all time there is a submission.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo thank you for your post. I do have braces after 
if ($_POST['submit']) { and after 
header('Location: page-thankyou.php');
exit;
}

Why won't this do?

Comment: You also have 2 `name` fields in your form. That's still not the problem though.

Comment: If your html file is in your `/` folder and email.php is in `/theme` folder, you may try to targer your action to `theme/email.php` ...

Comment: the form and the email are on the same directory? and where is the thank you page located?

Comment: Hi Alain, yes I'm trying to make it pickup first name and last name. I'm quite new to coding and was going to see what the result was once I receive a test email from myself.

Comment: Thanks alain, just tried it and same issue. URL now looking at http://charliesonlinestore.com/free-delivery-coupon-page/storefront/email.php

Comment: <div class="form">

    <form method="post" name="landing-page" action="storefront/email.php">

    First Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>

    Last Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>

    Email Address<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Okay, send me a voucher code!">

    </form>

Comment: since u using wordpress on the action you may have `action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/email.php` or `action="<?php echo site_url();?>/email.php"`

Comment: `header('Location: '.site_url().'/page-thankyou.php');`

Comment: Thanks for your comments masivuye, the thank you page is in the root theme folder as you may have guessed.

I tried your suggestions - "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/email.php in the action= within the form

header('Location: '.site_url().'/page-thankyou.php'); within the email.php file

Result: Internal server error 500. If I use the second line you provided, I receive the same issue as before. This is very strange.

Comment: God knows why I decided to write my own landing page, script and thank you page. Had to learn HTML and CSS from code academy from scratch and it took days to get the pages to work. I hope it's all worth it in the end! ;)

Comment: check the error log you will see why u getting the internal server error.

Comment: Change the results to an output like `if(mail ($to, $subject, $headers)){ echo "mail send"; } else{ echo "error sending mail";}` Then you see if the script is working. Maby there is an email send error. And also, what is the url on to the email.php. `http://charliesonlinestore.com/wp-content/themes/storefront/email.php` is the url where is sends at this moment. Is that correct?

Comment: To answer your question, yes that is the URL when I use @MasivuyeCokile 's first PHP action. If I take out that PHP action and just put action="email.php" it points to http://charliesonlinestore.com/email.php

Comment: i'm currently looking at your website, can u clear everything on email.php

Answer (score 1):

It tooks a little time before i saw it. The problem is your mail function. The php mail function needs a message before headers. And you replace your $header variable instead of extending it.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $to = 'charlie@charliesonlinestore.com';
    $body = 'Here your email body text';
    $subject = 'NEW Subscriber';
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'From: Your name <Charlie@charliesonlinestore.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    if($_POST['submit']){
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
             echo "mail send"; // change this later to your header location
        }
        else{
            echo 'error sending mail';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'no post data';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, interestingly I'm receiving a 

Error 500 - Internal Server Error

An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

So I think this is down to my server as I got this when using @MasivuyeCokile 's solution. I will investigate this further as there might be a server restriction of some sort. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to add - I received the above error after applying your solution. I copied and pasted it into the email.php.

Comment: Hmm. Okey it looks like we have to start from scratch. Remove everything from the file and just echo some text. `<?php echo "works"; ?>` and tell me if it's output works or if you still have the 500 error.

Comment: @CharlieMarsh clear everything, on the email page, and just echo any string as Paules suggested.

Comment: <?php echo "works"; ?> is in the email.php. Must be the hosting server? :s

Comment: I wasn't expecting responses this quick sorry!

Comment: I'm having a flick through this and it's asking me to check the error logs in cpanel http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/error-numbers/500-internal-server-error?tsrc=prechat

Comment: Interesting: [Mon Nov 28 04:26:47.467894 2016] [:error] [pid 219849:tid 139900030338816] [client 86.21.119.131:62294] SoftException in Application.cpp:269: File "/wp-content/themes/storefront/email.php" is writeable by others, referer: http://charliesonlinestore.com/free-delivery-coupon-page/ 

Receiving the above error. It might be permissions related.

Comment: Update: I am now receiving a message 'works' after changing permissions on the email.php from 777 to 644. I'll give the email.php a whirl with original text.

Comment: I would like to know why decreasing permissions fixes a problem like this.

Comment: It can be some cpanel security settings. if a file is 777 block all access. I don't know it for sure. I never worked with cpnael before.

Comment: Fantastic, the emails are sending and arriving to me successfully. Thank you for your help and also to @MasivuyeCokile . I need to do some playing around with the emails though as I'm noticing that it's not pulling through the form data and it's also ending up in my spam. Cheers guys! :)

Comment: the reason its not pulling through, u need to first check if the inputs are set and they are not empty, validate the email address, then when tht is done, u thne send the email

Comment: Hi guys, right I've updated the description with my new code and this is now sending emails but what ever I do, it will not pull through first name, last name and email address. I've married them up the best I can and have confirmed with my hosting company that all permissions are correct now. Is there anything that you can see? My head is HURTING ;)

Comment: Where in your code are you adding the name and email address to the message of the email? What is the actual language for the $body?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do I define that Jeff? Plenty of example php code online shows similar examples to the one I have. Erm, HTML?